# IOS 11 Camera labels not displaying in Local Phone language

Tags: ios, cordova, ios11, info.plist, cordova-ios

In the previous version of the IOS, Camera labels were displaying properly that is based on the local phone language camera labels were displaying correctly.

**For example** if phone language is in **German** ==> Then camera labels displayed were also in **German**

This was achieved buy adding language/culture code in the **Info.Plist** file.

But the same setting is present, but the labels are shown in English instead of local phone language.

Is there any setting which have to be included in Info.plist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging on the internet got the fix.

Before using the below values, it used to work.

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <array>
     <string>da-DK</string>
     <string>en-US</string>
  </array>
```

But now it works by using the below code

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
  <array>
     <string>da-DK</string>
     <string>en-US</string>
  </array>
```